# Importing larger CSV files to an empty table in a local MySQL database

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am building a local database made up of a handful of tables. The first few worked fine using the Export/Import option on the window that comes up after right clicking on a table and selection "Select Rows = Limit 1000."
[image]

Unfortunately, once I got to a table that has 30,000 rows, the feature stopped working. MySQL Workbench crashes after every attempt. The import/export wizard is also unhelpful.

I am reading the documentation on using the INLINE command (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), but it is not clear to me where to actually input the command. What command line tool do I use? Is there a better way to import data? Any advice would be highly valued for a new user.

Comment: Did you try the Table Data Import feature (see context menu for a schema)? That's the most flexible and direct way to import data.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I had tried this unsuccessfully,  but changed the data type of my key and it is uploading (slowly). For future reference, what do you (or others viewing this thread) know exactly which command line tool to use with the INLINE command? I don't think it's something I could enter into the SQL editor, and I am new to the interface so I am confused what other spaces there are.